# In PostgreSQL, filter with "IN" and "Order By" when there is a array in side of a JSON values

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-order-by

Lets assume table has below mentions fields and among those fields, "details" column keeps values in JSON format.

```
| id | firstName | lastName | title | details(json) |
```

example for json that keeps in details column can be like this

```
{
  "email": "example@gmail.com",
  "phoneNumber1": "+94111111111",
  "phoneNumber2": "+44111111111",
  "locations": [
    {
      "code": "LK",
      "name": "Sri Lanka",
      "lat": 128.12,
      "lon": 138.23
    },
    {
      "code": "UK",
      "name": "England",
      "lat": 148.12,
      "lon": 158.23
    },
    {
      "code": "IND",
      "name": "India",
      "lat": 163.12,
      "lon": 172.23
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to filter from locations code and same time need to order by details email.

As an example,

```
--------------------------------
details->>'code' IN ('LK','UK') 
ORDER BY details->>'email'
--------------------------------
```

PostgreSQL 13.4

Comment: Specify the version of postgreSQL you are using - answers can vary widely based on version employed.

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 13.4

Comment: Break it down.  Which part is not working, the WHERE  or the ORDER, and what else did you try to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this one using below mentioned query

The query,

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, details 
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT((person.details)::jsonb) as details, person.firstname, 
person.lastname
FROM person 
CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(person.details->'locations') AS locations
WHERE locations->>'code' IN ('LK','GB')
) as result
ORDER BY details->'email' DESC
```

Because, The ORDER BY clause can only be applied after the DISTINCT has been applied

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the PostgreSQL documentation for JSON data types.  Look here:

```
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html
```

In those docs, you will read that the jsonb data type can be used for indexing (and so can support your filtering needs).

You will also see references to functions that can extract properties from your JSON  column for use in ordering and filtering.

As a final suggestion, you may want to create user defined functions in your database to extract and return the relevant portions of your JSON data such that they become easy to use in SELECT statements, something like the following example...

```
   SELECT 
         GetEmailAddressFromJSON()
   FROM table 
   WHERE
      IsLocationCodeFromJSON(:locationCode)
   ORDER BY
      GetEmailAddressFromJSON()
```